# Combine background-size: cover and translateX

Tags: html, css

Assume I have a square div. If I load a 16:9 background image in it with `background-size` set to `cover` and I use `transform: translateX(-20px)` then the rest of the image is white. This is because the documentation states the image is clipped when it doesn't fit.

Is there any way to prevent that? The div acts as a preview for a selected area of another image. Depeding on the selection I have to move the background around so the user only sees the selected area.

Comment: Use `background-position` ?

Comment: Just use `background-position-x: -20px;`..!

Comment: That works. Thanks.